# Dynamic pictures for splash iOS 13

Tags: ios13, swift5, xcode11.5

I am using xcode 11.5. I need to show different picture every time on launch screen.

I tried so many things but nothing worked. I created a different view (Custom Splash) but it always displays the splash first and my custom view second.

How can i change splash screen ? or assign dynamic images to launch screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom splash screen but it's not possible with LaunchScreen

Comment: any idea how can i create the custom splash .. bcz i did that but it still shows the launch screen first and then move to that screen

Comment: It will always show the launch screen first only, You can make its view colour black for better transition look